# Typing a function parameter which accepts class instances using generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following function defined that binds a `this` context to a bunch of callbacks passed in the eventCallbackMap

```typescript
export function bindCallBacks<T>(target: ThisType<T>, eventCallbackMap: EventCallbackMap) {
    const entries = Object.entries(eventCallbackMap) as Entries<EventCallbackMap>;

    return entries.reduce<EventCallbackMap>((acc, [evtKey, callback]) => {
        if (callback) {
            (acc[evtKey] as unknown) = callback.bind(target);
        }
        return acc;
    }, {});
}
```

Which gets invoked like the following: (where `this` refers to a class instance)

```typescript
bindCallBacks(this, {
    'myEvent': this.handleEvent,
});
```

Note that I currently use an incorrect type for the target parameter since the `ThisType` utility is used to obtain the this context of functions.

How should I type the `target` parameter such that any class instance can be used (generics) and that the class type is automatically inferred from the class instance?
Ideally, I wouldn't want to write `bindCallbacks<ClassType>(this, callbackMap)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can type the target parameter as `T` and remove the `ThisType<T>` utility type. This will allow you to pass any class instance as the first argument to the `bindCallBacks` function, and the class type will be automatically inferred from the class instance. Please refer below:

```
export function bindCallBacks<T>(target: T, eventCallbackMap: EventCallbackMap) {
    const entries = Object.entries(eventCallbackMap) as Entries<EventCallbackMap>;

    return entries.reduce<EventCallbackMap>((acc, [evtKey, callback]) => {
        if (callback) {
            (acc[evtKey] as unknown) = callback.bind(target);
        }
        return acc;
    }, {});
}
```

with the above modification, you can invoke the `bindCallBacks` function like the below:

```
bindCallBacks(this, {
    'myEvent': this.handleEvent,
});
```

The class type will be automatically inferred from this argument, so you don’t need to explicitly specify the class type when calling the function.

Comment: However, when I hover over the function call,  the inferred type from the `target` parameter is `any`. See [this screenshot](https://pasteboard.co/FxrRflCAoxOP.png) for more info.